# The server tag is not well formed. QueryString and DataBinding

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, data-binding, connection-string

I've done a ton of research but with no luck finding a way to resolve this.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="(SELECT [TID], [CaseID]
  ,[dtTimeStamp]
  ,[Site]
  ,[Dept]
  ,[LocationDetail]
  ,[ContactPerson]
  ,[Phone]
  ,[contactEmail]
  ,[ProblemDesc]
FROM [hispcsupport_kb].[dbo].[tblCase] 
WHERE CaseID=" Request.QueryString("CaseID"))">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
</form>
```

From the error, this is the line causing the error.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="(SELECT [TID], [CaseID]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Change the SelectCommand to use a parameter: [Using Parameters with the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z72eefad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which will have the added benefit of removing the chance of an SQL injection attack. The "Community Additions" section at the end of that shows how to add the parameter with a value.

So...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="(SELECT [TID], [CaseID]
      ,[dtTimeStamp]
      ,[Site]
      ,[Dept]
      ,[LocationDetail]
      ,[ContactPerson]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[contactEmail]
      ,[ProblemDesc]
    FROM [hispcsupport_kb].[dbo].[tblCase] 
    WHERE CaseID = @CaseID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and in an appropriate place in the code-behind:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@CaseID", DbType.NVarChar, Request.QueryString("CaseID"))
```

(please change the DbType if required).

Comment: I like this approach more than mine.

Comment: With a bit of tweaking, this solution worked! Thank you all so much!

Comment: @user3779804 Feel free to mark my answer as the accepted answer if it basically solved your problem. It may help future readers of this thread to see what solved it, and may encourage them to use SQL parameters, which is almost always a better way to composite SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes around `Request.QueryString("CaseID")` are definitely one problem. You're already using double quotes for the `SelectCommand` element. Change the quotes around the `SelectCommand` to be single quotes:

```
SelectCommand='Select * from tblCase where CaseID=<%=Request.QueryString["CaseID"] %>'
```

Feel free to change the * back to a list of fields after you see that it works.

Comment: When fixed, the same error occurs. Any advice from this point?

Comment: I'd use this instead: `SelectCommand='Select * from tblCase where CaseID=<%=Request.QueryString["CaseID"] %>'`. Feel free to change the `*` back to a list of fields after you see that it works.

Comment: It does work without that, but I'm trying to use the querystring to open a specific record from a table when the user clicks on a link.

Comment: @user3779804 Updated the Command with the Querystring param included.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, btw. I tried the code and it says that there is incorrect syntax still. I've tried everything I can think of so far, to no avail.

Comment: No problem.. your first question was a good one. You included everything necessary to debug it.. the relevant code, error message, etc..